# Trapped by a Redstone Signal and command block around 50 blocks away

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got trapped in a position when I had an observer tping people to a position and it's stuck on repeat. Anybody who joins my LAN gets tpd. How do I remove the observer from almost 100 blocks away? I've tried /fill and don't know the coords and I don't want to abandon the world. It's really important. anybody know anything?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your earlier question. Please only post a question once.

Comment: Nonono, don't jump into the conclusion that fast this is a duplicate. Do you still having problems on the loop and you do not have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your on Bedrock, do this command:
/gamerule commandblocksenabled false
Then, when you’ve fixed it, do:
/gamerule commandblocksenabled true

For Java, use the F3 screen to find which coordinate axis (x, y, or z) the observer U.S. distances to you by (which of your axis coordinates has a different coordinate than the observer). Then, do something like this command:
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~100 ~10 ~10 air replace observer
(Note: in this example, the x acts is what distances you from the observer. The 10s are used as a buffer zone so if the block isn’t perfectly in line with you, it will still work. Also, this will replace all observers in the specified area